# Unable to get access to Router even though internet is working

Tags: router

I'm able to access internet but when I type 192.168.1.1 in the browser address bar, I'm unable to get router access, the page just won't open and I'm not even reaching password screen whereas earlier I used to access for this same router.

What could be the reason? What should I try?

Comment: Are you sure that the router's address is 192.168.1.1? Not all routers use this as the default and it may possible to change it as well. Which router (make and model) do you have?

Comment: What kind of router is this? Most routers use 192.168.1.1 as the web admin IP number, but some don't. If you have changed it or if something else is happening, you could always try resetting the router to factory defaults (the manufacturer's web-site or the documentation that came with the router should have details on how to do this).

Comment: Try pinging the router from a command prompt: (ping 192.168.1.1).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that when I try to go to 192.168.1.1 Firefox is not saying "Unable to connect" but instead it says "The connection was reset". I'm afraid if I reset router and 192.168.1.1 doesn't work I won't be able to even access internet as for our ISP we've to configure the modem which I won't be able to do if I don't get router access. Earlier it used to work on the same address.

Comment: @ed. : that seems to be working fine! I'm getting a reply while pinging.

Comment: It is althoug possible, that the router could only be configured from a special port. Or that you are connected by wifi, but the route is configured to only be reachable by a direct connection with a cable. You might have to take a look at the manual. If the ip is wrong try Win+R -> "cmd" -> ENTER and then "ipconfig" -> ENTER and look for the line with Gateway: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and use the ip written there to connect to the router.

Comment: Firefox sometimes exhibits "connection was reset" errors. You could try another browser, or clear your history/cache/cookies and try again with Firefox.

Comment: i've found on a recent setup, connected directly to modem then couldn't access router, don't know if that's normal and why, and was using router as a switch, but connecting directly to modem could be a cause .. also, depending on situation, IPs may need to be on the same domain or perhaps not(perhaps not if router is not just as a switch), try IPs on the same domain. If your "modem" has a private ip that is. So connect directly to the modem and do ipconfig to see modem's ip

Answer (score 20):

1. **Make sure you're using the right IP.**  Use `ipconfig` or a similar command to find out your Gateway address, and use that IP to access your router's page.
2. **Make sure you're connected directly.**  Some routers can be configured to not allow administration over Wi-Fi, or any other link not directly connected to the router.  So, make sure your connection is via a cable run directly from your computer to the router with *nothing else* in between.  Also, disable Wi-Fi on your computer to ensure that your machine is actually *using* the hard-line connection to reach the router.
3. **Make sure you can reach the router.**  Use `ping` to verify connectivity to the IP address, and `tracert` to confirm there's nothing between you and the router.
4. **Make sure you're using the right protocol.** Some routers can be configured to only permit administration over HTTPS, and may not have an appropriate HTTP->HTTPS redirect in place.  So, if `http://router-ip/` doesn't work, try `https://router-ip/`.
5. **Try a different browser.**  Some routers don't play nice with all browsers or browser extensions.  The most universally-compatible is usually IE.
6. **RTFM**  Just to make sure you didn't miss something obvious, or maybe something not-so-obvious which is specific to your router model.
7. **Factory Reset**  If all else fails, just push the little red button and hold it for about 30 seconds.  Bear in mind that this will of course erase any custom configuration you've done to the router, including administrator passwords and IP ranges.

Comment: An additional note on point (1): If your computer and router are both using a dual-stack setup you may have both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address listed for your default gateway. For me, it seems I can't connect to the router using its IPv4 address, only the IPv6 one.

Comment: this was driving me crazy, tried all steps randomly but when I stopped at step 4, it worked for me, when I entered https:// 192.168.1.1:8000 and finally loaded router's page felt like golden gates opening to me.

Comment: Perfect! I was having issues with point 4, was using https instead of http.

Comment: before 7, try a modem restart: turn off, then on. had always worked for me.

Comment: IT WAS JUST HTTPS! Omg, the hours of my life I won't get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are few reasons causing the router page to NOT to open in the browser. Since your internet is working that means there are no issues of connectivity between PC and router.

If IP address of Network card are configured to obtain automatically,    Change it to fill the **IP address manually**. For example if the    router IP is 192.168.1.1, Fill the IP address of PC's LAN as 192.168.1.x and similarly if the router IP is 192.168.0.1, fill-in the IP as 192.168.0.x.Now fill the default gateway as 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1.

If above method fails, try **connect router directly** to your    PC/Laptop with a ethernet cable. And now try to open the router page.

**Turn off firewall**.

I hope one of the above steps works or you can follow this link [[Fixed]Unable to Open 192.168.1.1 Router Configuration Web Page](http://www.it4nextgen.com/router-configuration-page/) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I have enabled https:// only access for the router, so it needed also the correct port number.
Try the following for Asus routers:

- https://192.168.1.1:8443
- http://router.asus.com
- https://router.asus.com:8443

See this article:
[Don’t enable HTTPS login on the ASUS RT-N66U (& how to fix it if you have)](https://jdrch.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/dont-enable-https-login-on-the-asus-rt-n66u-how-to-fix-it-if-you-have/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where 192.168.1.1 was directing me to the wrong router (the fios router that my wifi router was connected to). http://router.asus.com wasn't leading anywhere (nslookup showed that it didn't point to any IP address). I was online though, and I could connect to the router fine from other computers.

The problem was that my IP address was actually 192.168.50.x, not 192.168.1.x, so my router could be found on 192.168.50.1 not 192.168.1.1. Check your own IP address when looking for your router.

It turns out that my other computers were able to find the router via router.asus.com because they were having their DNS settings configured by the router. This one computer didn't work because I had set the DNS to 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem too and all of these useful solutions didn't help me... but I casually found that you have to remove all of devices connected to router, then you connect to router by one device only (by cable or any other ways)... and problem was solved.
Hope be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

The Cat 5 network cable needs to be connected on Port 1 of the router and back too the computer for gateway access.  The internet port on the router is only for the modem.  Disable all WiFi adapters on your PC/laptop and do a reboot this will flush out your IP configuration and your BIOS this will allow a direct communication with the Ethernet card.

I troubleshooted my problem turned out I was using the wrong ports on the router.

Answer (score 0):

I can log into the D-Link DIR-615 using Microsoft's Internet Explorer only.
Other browsers try https: only and will not use http:

Answer (score 0):

For me switching from chrome to safari worked.