# Unable to load (blank white screen) local router default gateway 192.168.1.1

Tags: networking, google-chrome, router, lan, google-chrome-extensions

Chrome is not loading my default gateway anymore. The LAN port is working properly. IE is able to render the page, also Chrome in incognito. The closest answer seems to be in a [foxfire environment.](https://superuser.com/questions/337334/unable-to-get-access-to-router-even-though-internet-is-working)

Thanks in advance!

Environment:

Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m (up to date) 
Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit 
Linksys E8350 Firmware Version: 1.0.02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnecting the connection on a newly installed VPN proxy [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/betternet-unlimited-free/gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm) worked as suggested [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8An6FHiQdg8).