# Can't connect to my router's configuration page ... 1 minute after factory reset

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I've been trying to access my router's configuration page without success and it's driving me crazing right now.

The internet is working fine, and I can connect to WiFi using the router's default password.

I have a Motorolla SBG6580 (modem + router). I've tried [everything listed here](https://superuser.com/questions/337334/unable-to-get-access-to-router-even-though-internet-is-working) to connect to the configuration page:

> - Checked the IP address of the default gateway of the router (192.168.0.1) and the modem (192.168.100.1).
> - I'm using an Ethernet connection directly between my computer and the router.
> - I've tried http, https, diffrent ports, nothing works.
> - I've tried multiple browsers and disabling firewalls and antiviruses on Windows, nothing worked. Also tried the same on Linux, doesn't work either.

The strangest part is that when I reset the router to the factory settings, I can access the configuration page normally for about one minute or so after the router reboots (simply typing 192.168.0.1 in the chrome address bar), then I start having problems again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out my ISP was blocking me from configuring my router...